# How to change the color of the Eclipse's marker on the right of the scroll?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to change the color of this little marker of the occurrence, on the right of the scroll?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/mark_occurrences.htm (Window | Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations - Occurrences), but it seems it also changes the color of the hightlighted text.

Comment: Yes, looks like they're tied... :/